# Scroll problem with my android mouse

Tags: chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android

I have a [HUAWEI MediaPad M5 Lite 10 tablet](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07G3JFHJR/?tag=hu2-21) I use it with a mouse connected to USB thanks to [this adapter](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07YWW8C6X/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

For some time with my mouse, I can no longer scroll through the pages of browsers like Firefox or Chrome where another browser.

Rather than scrolling the text from top to bottom or vice versa, it selects the text for me!

I can no longer also do a copy / paste in the web pages, it selects but without displaying "copy / paste" I reset my tablet but it doesn't change anything.

I reset my tablet by following [this procedure](https://www.hardreset.info/fr/devices/huawei/huawei-mediapad-m5-108/) but it doesn't change anything.

I changed the adapter, tried with another mouse, with a bluetooth mouse but it's the same :(

I sent my tablet to the after-sales service 3 times for this problem but it came back each time as repaired but the problem is still present.

The funny thing is that when I take control of my tablet with my computer and with teamviewer I use my computer mouse! Well it works.

I can scroll web pages through my computer. An idea ? Thank you

Comment: You did not include this detail in your questions but I assume by "scrolling" you are referring to pressing and holding the left mouse button and then moving the mouse which also moves the scrollable screen under the mouse cursor. Does "scrolling" work in other apps or has it changed in every app on your tablet?

Comment: Yes I am actually talking about pressing and raising or lowering.
The scroll works perfectly with the rest of the applications.It is only defective with web browsers

Comment: Then the web browsers mimic "desktop/PC behavior". May be you should simply use the scroll wheel on your mouse?

Comment: Unfortunately I am disabled and I do not have a wheel on my mouse I do not understand because a few months ago it was working very well It looks like there is something on the android side that has changed

Comment: Could someone test it with a mouse without it and see if they can scroll a web page by holding the left click?

Comment: I tried it, it is the same on my tablet. May be there is a configuration option or flag that disables this behavior. I assume you may get better results directly asking the Chrome/Firefox developers.

Comment: I will try to contact the developers